# how to create a pytorch NN with 2 hidden layer with nn.Sequential?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

how to add an another hidden layer in this 1 layer model? :

```
model = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([ ('fc1', nn.Linear(D_in, H)), 
                                    ('Tanh', nn.Tanh()),
                                    ('fc2', nn.Linear(H, D_out))]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You an do this by separating the original hidden layer into two or adding another hidden layer:

```
model = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([ ('fc1', nn.Linear(D_in, H1)),
                                    ('act1', nn.Tanh()),
                                    ('fc2', nn.Linear(H1, H2)),
                                    ('act2', nn.Tanh()),
                                    ('fc3', nn.Linear(H2, D_out)) ]))
```

The only thing you got to do is take the 1st hidden layer (H1) as input to the next Linear layer which will output to another hidden layer (H2) then we add another Tanh activation layer and then lastly, we add a Linear layer which takes the H2 layer as input and the outputs to the number of output nodes.